# Gettext dose not work on my real server?

Tags: php, html

I used php gettext, and it works on my localhost but it's not work on real server?

```
require_once("gettext/lib/gettext.php");
require_once("gettext/lib/streams.php");

$local_file = new FileReader("gettext/local/{$_SESSION['lang_temp']}/LC_MESSAGES/dary.mo");
$local_fetch=new gettext_reader($local_file);
function _($text){
    global $local_fetch;
    return $local_fetch->translate($text);
}
```

Comment: Check your console. Your path could be incorrect on the server.

Comment: i check it is correct

Comment: Any errors then? Can you check permission on the file? Is it readable?

Comment: no error display just dont display all the page before and after of the text file and check the permission what do you mean from where i should chech i think there is no premission on this file